Ionic 8 Input outline floating label with icon label fixed on top issue
When I try to put a icon under input tag with floating label, my label fixed on top without any value in input
my input value black, after I add icon it's pushed to top
enter image description here
I expect when I used a input floating label with icon, I need my label in normal place not on top

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You need to add code that you have tried. Also I would suggest to add the icon separately at the start of ion-input to correctly render the label.
